# Add two forms in a page (plone)

Tags: python, forms, plugins, plone

I'm developing a plugin for Plone. I have to show two different forms in a single page: two complete disjoint forms that will submit to two different pages. I've followed  this tutorial http://docs.plone.org/develop/addons/helloworld/extend/form.html but with my actual low knowledge on Plone development I cannot figure out how to do this.

Comment: Have a look at the [`z3c.form` subform guide](https://pythonhosted.org/z3c.form/subform.html).

Comment: Also, you need to elaborate on what you exactly mean by two different forms - are they siblings, sub-objects or two complete disjoint forms that will submit to two different endpoints.  Would be great if you edit your question here later with what you have tried.  You might also want to look at this more comprehensive [documentation](http://docs.plone.org/develop/plone/forms/z3c.form.html#subforms), and other relevant sections there.

Comment: If they are two complete, disjoint forms then just have them at their separate endpoints, since by default Zope/Plone forms generally get submitted to the same origin as its source (i.e. form at `/portal/form_a` will submit to `/portal/form_a`).  Your design generally will be cleaner, unless you can clearly state what special snowflake case that absolutely require this.  It really is best for you to understand the basics first before moving onto the more advanced use cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not a Zope expert and you *really* want to provide two different form in the same view (but let me say that suggestions in comments above are good: are your sure you *really* need this?) I don't suggest you to use `z3c.form`.

You can stay simple and draw the HTML yourself.

1- Register a new view

See http://docs.plone.org/develop/plone/views/browserviews.html#creating-a-view-using-zcml

2- Use simple HTML in the template, and add there two forms:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en"
      xmlns:tal="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/tal"
      xmlns:metal="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/metal"
      metal:use-macro="context/main_template/macros/master">
<body>

<metal:content-core fill-slot="content-core">
    <metal:content-core define-macro="content-core">

       <form action="@@endpoint1" method="post">
           <!-- your HTML here -->
       </form>

       <form action="@@endpoint2" method="post">
           <!-- your HTML here -->
       </form>

    </metal:content-core>
</metal:content-core>

</body>
</html>
```

Knowing [TAL](http://docs.plone.org/adapt-and-extend/theming/templates_css/template_basics.html) will help you if you don't need a static HTML (that is a very uncommon case).

3- Add two additional views (`endpoint1` and `endpoint2`) where you (probably) don't need to provide any template, but simple some logic.

---

It's really simple, you will be able to starts quickly... **but** you must handle yourself validation and server-side redirect. Sadly `z3c.form` could simplify for you a lot of this stuff.